# Why is OpenJDK 8 not pulling proper JavaFX libraries when using Docker?

Tags: java, maven, docker, javafx

I have a java program that I wrote. The main things include OpenJDK8, Maven, and JavaFX. The program builds and runs on its own. I want to put it in a Docker container, but I'm having trouble getting it to build.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk
FROM maven:3.3-jdk-8-onbuild
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends openjfx && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
CMD ["java","-jar","target/"CodeDemo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

Here is what I ran to build the container:

```
sudo docker build -t java-maven-code-demo .
```

Here is the error I keep getting complaining about no javafxpackager:

> Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec
>   (unpack-dependencies) on project CodeDemo: Command execution failed.
>   Cannot run program
>   "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../bin/javafxpackager" (in
>   directory "/usr/src/app"): error=2, No such file or directory -> [Help
>   1]

I have all the files in a CodeDemo directory. At the top level, I have src, target, Dockerfile, pom.xml. In target, I have the compiled jar.

I'm confused by the error because I thought Java 8 OpenJDK came with JavaFX. So, if I'm pulling OpenJDK, I should be gettng the things I need for JavaFX ([similar question on GitHub](https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/issues/158) - solution still gave the error though).

Can anyone point me in the direction of what I could be doing wrong? Is there something else I should be doing to get the proper libraries?

Comment: You have multiple FROM lines. Based from your Dockerfile, only the maven base image will be used. Maybe try installing openjdk through another RUN statement before installing openjfx?

Comment: I also don't see any COPY statement in your Dockerfile. I initially assumed "CodeDemo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" exists by default on the maven image but I just tried building the image and it doesn't exist. If that's the jar file from your Java program, don't forget to add it through a `COPY` statement in your Dockerfile.

Comment: @libzz Thank you! Both of those suggestions solved the problem. Side note: I ended up ADD instead of COPY. I tried COPY too out of curiosity though, and it works as well (which seems to make sense off of docs I've read). If you write your comments as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple `FROM` lines. Based from your Dockerfile, only the maven base image will be used. Maybe try installing openjdk through another `RUN` statement before installing openjfx?

I also don't see any `COPY` statement in your Dockerfile. I initially assumed `CodeDemo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` exists by default on the maven image but I just tried building the image and it doesn't exist. If that's the jar file from your Java program, don't forget to add it through a `COPY` statement in your Dockerfile.